# Beamer - compile only notes?

Tags: beamer, notes

Is it possible to compile only beamer notes without slides?

For practice I only wanted print the notes but I could not find any way to do so.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use

```
\setbeameroption{show only notes}
```

Comment: My slides typically may have overlays, but the speaking notes never do. I find it useful to have ``\documentclass[handout]\setbeameroption{show only notes}`` as a one-line commented out option.

Answer (score 20):

I always have the following three on my slides:

```
%\documentclass[notes]{beamer}
%\documentclass[notes=hide]{beamer}
\documentclass[notes=only]{beamer}
```

Then I comment or uncomment them according to my needs. As should be clear, the last one prints only notes, whereas the others print everything and no notes respectively.

Comment: Thanks! It was so easy. I don't know how I missed it. :)

Comment: The document option `notes` is obsolete and issues a warning when used. Instead, you should use `\setbeameroption{show notes}`/`\setbeameroption{hide notes}`/`\setbeameroption{show only notes}`, as [Gonzalo suggested](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20228/3323).